# Displaying time ago like Twitter

Tags: java, android, time, java-time

I am using `DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString()` for displaying when a post is made.

The string it returns is something like that: **1 minute ago**, but I would like to be **1 m** or **1 h** and so on (shortened and without ago).

I can replace “hour” with “h” or “minute” with “m” but if the language is different from English it won’t work. It's what `Twitter` is using right now. **English/Cyrillic** way of displaying by Twitter.

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**: I will accept the answer from @Bradley Wilson although I will add here cleaner solution (using again the JodaTime package). Also the rest of the answers also can be modified for the same result so they deserve up vote. Thank you, all:

```
    DateTime postMaded = new DateTime(your previous date);
    DateTime nowUpdate = new DateTime();

    Period period = new Period(postMaded, nowUpdate);

    PeriodFormatter formatter;

    Locale current = ConverterMethods.getCurrentLocale();

    if (current.getLanguage().contentEquals(any Cyrillic language )) {

        if (period.getYears() != 0) {
            formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().appendYears().appendSuffix(" г.").printZeroNever().toFormatter();
        } else if (period.getMonths() != 0) {
            formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().appendMonths().appendSuffix(" м").printZeroNever().toFormatter();
        } else if (period.getWeeks() != 0) {
            formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().appendWeeks().appendSuffix(" седм.").printZeroNever().toFormatter();
        } else if (period.getDays() != 0) {
            formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().appendDays().appendSuffix(" д").printZeroNever().toFormatter();
        } else if (period.getHours() != 0) {
            formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().appendHours().appendSuffix(" ч").printZeroNever().toFormatter();
        } else if (period.getMinutes() != 0) {
            formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().appendMinutes().appendSuffix(" мин").printZeroNever().toFormatter();
        } else {
            formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().appendSeconds().appendSuffix(" с").printZeroNever().toFormatter();
        }

    } else {

        if (period.getYears() != 0) {
            formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().appendYears().appendSuffix(" y").printZeroNever().toFormatter();
        } else if (period.getMonths() != 0) {
            formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().appendMonths().appendSuffix(" mon").printZeroNever().toFormatter();
        } else if (period.getWeeks() != 0) {
            formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().appendWeeks().appendSuffix(" w").printZeroNever().toFormatter();
        } else if (period.getDays() != 0) {
            formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().appendDays().appendSuffix(" d").printZeroNever().toFormatter();
        } else if (period.getHours() != 0) {
            formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().appendHours().appendSuffix(" h").printZeroNever().toFormatter();
        } else if (period.getMinutes() != 0) {
            formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().appendMinutes().appendSuffix(" m").printZeroNever().toFormatter();
        } else {
            formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().appendSeconds().appendSuffix(" s").printZeroNever().toFormatter();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Joda-Time (https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android) has some nice options for doing things like that.

Comment: It would be helpful if you specify packages which contain `Period`,  `PeriodFormatter`, `PeriodFormatterBuilder` classes

Comment: I added it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JodaTime](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android) to achieve this:

Add the dependency to your app level `Build.Gradle` file like so:

```
compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.4.1'
```

and then you can just simply implement this functionality.

```
private String time = "Just Now";

private String how_long_ago(String created_at) {
        DateTime sinceGraduation = new DateTime(created_at, GregorianChronology.getInstance());
        DateTime currentDate = new DateTime(); //current date

        Months diffInMonths = Months.monthsBetween(sinceGraduation, currentDate);
        Days diffInDays = Days.daysBetween(sinceGraduation, currentDate);
        Hours diffInHours = Hours.hoursBetween(sinceGraduation, currentDate);
        Minutes diffInMinutes = Minutes.minutesBetween(sinceGraduation, currentDate);
        Seconds seconds = Seconds.secondsBetween(sinceGraduation, currentDate);

        Log.d("since grad", "before if " + sinceGraduation);
        if (diffInDays.isGreaterThan(Days.days(31))) {
            time = diffInMonths.getMonths() + " months ago";
            if (diffInMonths.getMonths() == 1) {
                time = diffInMonths.getMonths() + " month ago";
            } else {
                time = diffInMonths.getMonths() + " months ago";
            }
            return time;
        } else if (diffInHours.isGreaterThan(Hours.hours(24))) {
            if (diffInDays.getDays() == 1) {
                time = diffInDays.getDays() + " day ago";
            } else {
                time = diffInDays.getDays() + " days ago";
            }
            return time;
        } else if (diffInMinutes.isGreaterThan(Minutes.minutes(60))) {
            if (diffInHours.getHours() == 1) {
                time = diffInHours.getHours() + " hour ago";
            } else {
                time = diffInHours.getHours() + " hours ago";
            }
            return time;
        } else if (seconds.isGreaterThan(Seconds.seconds(60))) {
            if (diffInMinutes.getMinutes() == 1) {
                time = diffInMinutes.getMinutes() + " minute ago";
            } else {
                time = diffInMinutes.getMinutes() + " minutes ago";
            }
            return time;
        } else if (seconds.isLessThan(Seconds.seconds(60))) {
            return time;
        }
        Log.d("since grad", "" + sinceGraduation);
        return time;
    }
```

Just change the `String` output for `time` to achieve the desired '1m'

**Note**: you can use localization to change the string through your resources.

see [Android Localization Tutorial](https://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/android-application-localization-tutorial/) for more details.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the [PrettyTime](http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettytime/) library.

It's quite simple to use:

`import org.ocpsoft.prettytime.PrettyTime`

```
PrettyTime p = new PrettyTime();
System.out.println(p.format(new Date()));
// prints "moments ago"
```

or can also pass in a locale for internationalized messages:

```
PrettyTime p = new PrettyTime(new Locale("fr"));
System.out.println(p.format(new Date()));
// prints "à l'instant"
```

As noted in the comments, Android has this functionality built into the [`android.text.format.DateUtils`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString%28long%29) class.

Comment: As I said I am using DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString() it works ok. But I would like to customize the output in every language. See the images

Comment: It's second option first you try this library `PrettyTime`.

Comment: One problem: I don't see any way to realize abbreviated style, see as example also this [resource](https://github.com/ocpsoft/prettytime/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/ocpsoft/prettytime/i18n/Resources_en.java). The OP seems to have a strong wish for configurable text width, see also my answer.

Comment: @ionicorn Is it helpful to you?

Answer (score 3):

you can use this function to do that

```
  public static String getTimeAgo(long time) {
     if (time < 1000000000000L) {
     // if timestamp given in seconds, convert to millis
     time *= 1000;
  }

  long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
  if (time > now || time <= 0) {
     return null;
  }

  // TODO: localize
  final long diff = now - time;
  if (diff < MINUTE_MILLIS) {
     return "just now";
  } else if (diff < 2 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
     return "a minute ago";
  } else if (diff < 50 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
     return diff / MINUTE_MILLIS + " min ago";
  } else if (diff < 90 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
     return "an hour ago";
  } else if (diff < 24 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
     return diff / HOUR_MILLIS + " hours ago";
  } else if (diff < 48 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
     return "yesterday";
  } else {
     return diff / DAY_MILLIS + " days ago";
  }
 }
```

Comment: No, I can't because if the language is not English it won't enter in any of your cases. For example in Cyrillic minute/min is "минута/мин"

Comment: you can use string resources for your localization @ionicorn

Answer (score 1):

Using my library [Time4A](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A) would work like you have specified in your question:

**Printing relative times (with ago-word)**

```
    PlainTimestamp now = PlainTimestamp.nowInSystemTime();
    PlainTimestamp earlier = now.minus(1, ClockUnit.MINUTES);
    Moment past = earlier.inStdTimezone();
    Locale russian = new Locale("ru");

    PrettyTime.of(Locale.ENGLISH).printRelativeInStdTimezone(past);
    // output: 1 minute ago

    PrettyTime.of(Locale.ENGLISH)
       .withShortStyle().printRelativeInStdTimezone(past);
    // output: 1 min. ago

    PrettyTime.of(russian).printRelativeInStdTimezone(past);
    // output: 1 минуту назад

    PrettyTime.of(russian).withShortStyle().printRelativeInStdTimezone(past);
    // output: 1 мин. назад
```

**Printing flat times without ago-word**

```
    IsoUnit days = CalendarUnit.DAYS;
    IsoUnit hours = ClockUnit.HOURS;
    IsoUnit minutes = ClockUnit.MINUTES;
    net.time4j.Duration<IsoUnit> d =
        Duration.in(Timezone.ofSystem(), days, hours, minutes)
            .between(earlier, now);

    PrettyTime.of(Locale.ENGLISH).print(d, TextWidth.WIDE);
    // output: 1 minute

    PrettyTime.of(Locale.ENGLISH).print(d, TextWidth.ABBREVIATED);
    // output: 1 min

    PrettyTime.of(Locale.ENGLISH).print(d, TextWidth.NARROW);
    // output: 1m

    PrettyTime.of(russian).print(d, TextWidth.WIDE);
    // output: 1 минута

    PrettyTime.of(russian).print(d, TextWidth.ABBREVIATED);
    // output: 1 мин

    PrettyTime.of(russian).print(d, TextWidth.NARROW);
    // output: 1 мин
```

The newest library version uses the data of CLDR-repository v30.0.2 (from Unicode-consortium, actually in 80 languages). If necessary you might wish to change the text resources by defining your own assets to be distributed together with Time4A (then overriding the default assets).